# Filtering Subform Based On Parent

Tags: 2010, form, access

I am working on a timesheet system, and I am trying to create an Access form to show in SharePoint.  I have a parent form with a subform that is based on a crosstab query (projects along the side, dates along the top, hours in between).  However, I am having some trouble with the filtering.  I am trying to filter the query based on a value in the parent form, which will hopefully be set by the SharePoint site when I am finished.  I have created a macro that will switch the subform from a blank form to the form containing the data (as the form will not load otherwise, due to the filter not having a value).  This macro works perfectly when the filter is not in place.  However, when I apply the filter, the form that the subform is switching to shows the data as expected, but the subform view in the main form is completely blank.  I'm not sure what the issue is, but there are no errors, and as I said the form shows the data when opened by itself.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem was in the way that I was changing the form source.  I currently have a working solution, and I make the change by using a 'BrowseTo' macro action and specifying the filter value as a parameter, rather than pulling it from the main form.